# Remove mirror lines in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, igraph

I'm R begginer and this question may appear quite naive but I try to create a network based on family relationships among a population. I'm working with R package igraph.

Preparing my data, I'm ending having this kind of dataframe

```
Source    Target    Distance
Actr22510 Actr22509        1
Actr22511 Actr22509        1
Actr22509 Actr22510        1
Actr22511 Actr22510        1
Actr57033 Actr22510        1
Actr22509 Actr22511        1
```

The network I'm trying to build out of this is non-oriented. In this case, the lines Actr22510-Actr22509 and Actr22509-Actr22510 are the same. I don't need them to appear both in my dataframe.

Is it possible to remove these kind of mirror lines ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the ultimate goal is to create an undirected *igraph* object, may be you don't need to remove these lines at all. Simply:

```
library(igraph)

# Create an undirected graph, with edges between "Source" and "Target"
# Distance is kept as an edge attribute.
g <- graph.data.frame(df, directed=FALSE)

# Remove multiple edges (originally created from "mirror" lines)
g <- simplify(g, remove.multiple=TRUE, remove.loops=FALSE, edge.attr.comb="first")
```

Comment: No, edge attributes are combined by one of several options. See [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/igraph/docs/attribute.combination) for these options, and [here](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/igraph/docs/simplify) for the `simplify` functions.

Comment: My bad. You need to define the edge attribute combination function when you call `simplify`. I updated the code.

Comment: Done. Thanks for catching it!!

Answer (score 2):

One option is to sort the first two columns of each row, and then concatenate, and then check whether these keys are duplicated:

```
    df <-structure(list(Source = c("Actr22510", "Actr22511", "Actr22509", "Actr22511", "Actr57033", "Actr22509"), 
                    Target = c("Actr22509", "Actr22509", "Actr22510", "Actr22510", "Actr22510", "Actr22511"), 
                    Distance = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L)), 
                    .Names = c("Source","Target", "Distance"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-6L))
df$key <- apply(df[,1:2],1,FUN=function(x)paste(sort(x),collapse=" "))
df[!duplicated(df$key),]
#Source    Target Distance                 key
#1 Actr22510 Actr22509        1 Actr22509 Actr22510
#2 Actr22511 Actr22509        1 Actr22509 Actr22511
#4 Actr22511 Actr22510        1 Actr22510 Actr22511
#5 Actr57033 Actr22510        1 Actr22510 Actr57033
```

As you prefer not to use the `apply` function, this may be easier to understand:

```
df$key <- ifelse(df$Source < df$Target,  paste(df$Source,df$Target), paste(df$Target,df$Source)

df[!duplicated(df$key),]
```

Comment: Thanks, this apply function works but it's a really nightmare for R beginners to understand it. Can you explain what's FUN for ? Why can't it just be `df[!duplicated(df$Source),]`.

Comment: The apply() function loops over each row, and on each row it does FUN, i.e. sorts the first two elements of the row, and pastes them into one string. This creates a key which depends on the two elements, but not their order. I've updated the answer with a version that might be easier to understand if you don't like apply functions, but would encourage you to read up on them, as they're often a core part of using R efficiently.
To answer your question, your code, @r.let,  would only look for different sources, not different pairs.

Comment: I've read we are not supposed to give thanks in comments but you took time to explain and now I understand how this apply function works, it can be useful for next step into R. So thanks !